# Global listener for network status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

In which way I can do a **global** listener(or whatever) checking if we have internet connection visible in **whole app** no matter what controller I'm in and inside it using function showing simple angular material Alert in every app view.

So if I need to invoke this in any controller, I guess there's another way to do this, but I dont know how.

listener I wrote using addEventListener way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to that event in the `run` section

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window) {
  $rootScope.online = $window.navigator.onLine;
  if (!$rootScope.online) {
    //do actions here
    //for example go to special state, $state.go('offline')
    alert('Offline!');
  }

  $window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    //do actions here
    //for example set $rootScope.online = false;
    alert('Offline!');
  }, false);

  $window.addEventListener("online", function() {
    //do actions here, 
    //for example set $rootScope.online = true;
    alert('Online!');
  }, false);
}])
```

1) Since it's in the `run` block, it's quite on top of the hierarchy; executed when app is bootstrapped; I use this approach in several projects and and it works in all controllers;

2)The first **if** check is for first-time initial app start-up phase; because that may be that you are

- using **service workers** and can app UI even when being offline;
- user saved a shortcut on mobile with "Add to homescreen"

Comment: Can I add into this function creating alert if we're offline, or in another place?
So this run will be visible in whole app(I see you using $rootScope) without having to use a some sort controller?

Comment: what part of the proposed code is unclear ? do you get an simple browser alert correctly when switching online/offline if you use this?

Comment: Code is in 99% clear, I did it in similar way, but I have concern if I can only do this, and in any place in my app I will be able to see my alerts?
I have only one question for this first if statement, why use this if we have addEventListener down below. This is for global action? In conclusion I guess there isn't any need to use interval method to invoke this cause we have dynamic checking?

Comment: how can I check my online status in another controller (module) eg. using onsubmit form function? I add that my .run block is global that mean it isn't in any module.
I don't wanna add addEventListener in my controller, I want to use listener in my global .run block.

Comment: pls read code in my example carefully - you can set '$rootScope.online' property value and then access in it ANY controller or directive;

Comment: $rootScope.online doesn't work as I want to, but I create some other $rootScope flag and then set it in addEventListener and now it works as I want. Sorry for those silly questions but I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Offline](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome)

Or roll your own

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

.factory('OnlineStatus', function($timeout) {
  var isOnlineNow = true,
    isOnline = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        isOnlineNow = true;
      });
    },
    isOffline = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        isOnlineNow = false;
      });
    };

  if (window.addEventListener) {
    /*
     Works well in Firefox and Opera with the 
     Work Offline option in the File menu.
     Pulling the ethernet cable doesn't seem to trigger it.
     Later Google Chrome and Safari seem to trigger it well
     */
    window.addEventListener("online", isOnline, false);
    window.addEventListener("offline", isOffline, false);
  }
  else {
    /*
     Works in IE with the Work Offline option in the 
     File menu and pulling the ethernet cable
     */
    document.body.ononline = isOnline;
    document.body.onoffline = isOffline;
  }

  return {
    isOnline:function() {
      return isOnlineNow;
    }
  };
})
.directive('online', ['OnlineStatus', function(OnlineStatus) {
  return {
    template:'<div class="online"></div>',
    replace:true,
    restrict:'E',
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return OnlineStatus.isOnline();
      }, function(isOnline) {
        elem.html(isOnline ? 'Online' : "Offline");
      })
    }
  };
}])
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/DrW8UdYsediusRMu1aMo?p=preview